# How to make that STS don't restart server after my edits in jsp?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How to make that STS (Spring-Tool-Suit) don't restart server after my edits in jsp?

Why STS make so? This is not necessary, I think?

Comment: STS = spring tool suit (eclipse)

Comment: I guess,without restart,changes in won't effect,because of cached copy

Comment: I edit client side. I want that server works as before

Comment: Sometimes STS restart server(tomcat) and somtimes doesn't make so.when it doesn't restart - I saw my changes on jsp page

Answer (score 1):

By default STS monitors all files on the classpath for changes to trigger restarts. You can exclude resources from triggering an automatic restart using the following config option: `http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable`

#### Reference

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude

Comment: For my case, I wanted to enable the sts auto restart on JS (static) files changes which were located in another maven module (project). So I just use "link source" option of main project's "Build path" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the server View, double click on your Tomcat instance. This will open the properties of your Tomcat server. As I am not sure of which parameter will help you to solve your problem, check the following options in the latter view:

- Automatic Publishing, option "Override default settings" selected, 1 second for the publishing interval.
- In server options, uncheck options "Server modules without publishing" and "publish module contexts to separate XML files".
- In the modules tab, for each modules deployed, check that Auto Reload is enabled.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I want restart server if edit my java code and don't restart if I edit jsp. It really?

Comment: And I want that it makes automatically

Comment: is your context reloadable? check your `context.xml` for `<Context reloadable="true">`

Comment: There are located context.xml ?

Comment: I don't know there is context.xml on mu pc

Comment: it is in your server- and/or web-project

Comment: i know. you said that